# checking how many div have a certain class

Tags: jquery, html

I need to check how many divs have the certain class "visible". I went about it like this but this is clearly wrong:

```
var select = $(".container div:not(.row)").hasClass("visible");
alert("there are " + select.length + "divs with the class visible");
```

how Could I achieve what I'm trying to do?

Comment: Maybe it's just the doubled "s" in `hassClass`

Comment: just a typo? hassClass should be hasClass

Comment: You can try `$('.visible').length`

Comment: @SnakesandCoffee I just made the typo here not in my actual script

Answer (score 0, accepted):

do it in one:

```
alert("there are " + $(".container div.visible:not(.row)").length + "divs...");
```

Answer (score 0):

Try like this.

```
alert("there are " + $(".visible").size() + " divs with the class visible");
```